# document.cookie is empty in angular 2 component - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, cookies, components

I'm working on an `Angular 2` app which has some components including `LoginComponent` and `CompanyComponent`.

I use `ng2-cookies` npm package in order to manage cookies. I set some cookies in`LoginComponent` but can't get them in `CompanyComponent`!

LoginComponent :

```
alert(document.cookie) // has results
```

CompanyComponent :

```
alert(document.cookie) // no results
```

Comment: And the URL _paths_ of those components are which, and what path was the cookie set as valid for ...?

Comment: @CBroe `paths` are different, is it because of `path` values? How to get cookies of other `paths`?

Comment: You don't get cookies if the path doesn't match - that is the _purpose_ of the path parameter when setting a cookie, that you can limit it's "visibility" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/80943592?noredirect=1)'s comment

the problem causes by different `path`s. so I
set cookies like so :

```
Cookie.set(Cookies.names.username, data.username, 1, '/');
```